# No change in loss while training Deep Convolutional GAN on CIFAR10 dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

The model is not training at all. I think the gradients are not flowing properly or maybe there is some logical error.

There is no change in loss even after few epochs.
I tried with many variations of the code but could not debug the problem.

**No change in discriminator and generator loss.**

Below is my code:

```
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Dense, LeakyReLU, BatchNormalization, Reshape 
from keras.layers import Flatten, Input, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, AlphaDropout, Conv2DTranspose
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras.datasets import cifar10
import keras.backend as K
import cv2
import pickle
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class CifarGAN:
    def __init__(self, img_rows, img_cols, channels, epochs, batch_size, latent_dim):
        self.img_rows = img_rows
        self.img_cols = img_cols
        self.channels = channels
        self.img_shape = (self.img_rows, self.img_cols, self.channels)
        self.epochs = epochs
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.latent_dim = latent_dim

        self.optimizer = Adam(0.0002, beta_1=0.5)

        # build and compile the discriminator
        self.discriminator = self.build_discriminator()
        self.discriminator.compile(optimizer=self.optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

        # build and compile generator
        self.generator = self.build_generator()
        self.generator.compile(optimizer=self.optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy')        

        # input noise
        noise = Input((self.latent_dim, ))
        img = self.generator(noise)

        # for the combined model we will only train the generator
        self.discriminator.trainable = False

        valid = self.discriminator(img)

        self.combined = Model(inputs=noise, outputs=valid, name='combined')
        self.combined.compile(optimizer=self.optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy')
        # self.combined.summary()

    def build_generator(self):

        model = Sequential(name='generator')

        model.add(Dense(256*4*4, name='gen_dense_2'))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2, name='gen_lr_2'))

        model.add(Reshape((4, 4, 256), name='gen_reshape_1'))

        model.add(Conv2DTranspose(128, kernel_size=(4, 4), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
        # model.add(BatchNormalization(name='gen_bc_1'))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2, name='gen_lr_3'))
        # model.add(AlphaDropout(0.1))

        model.add(Conv2DTranspose(128, kernel_size=(4, 4), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
        # model.add(BatchNormalization(name='gen_bc_2'))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2, name='gen_lr_4'))
        # model.add(AlphaDropout(0.1))

        model.add(Conv2DTranspose(256, kernel_size=(4, 4), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
        # model.add(BatchNormalization(name='gen_bc_3'))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2, name='gen_lr_5'))
        # model.add(AlphaDropout(0.1))

        model.add(Conv2D(3, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='tanh'))

        noise = Input((self.latent_dim, ), name='gen_input')
        img = model(noise)
        # model.summary()
        return Model(noise, img)


    def build_discriminator(self):
        model = Sequential(name='discriminator')

        model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='dis_conv_1'))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(name='dis_bc_1'))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2, name='dis_lr_1'))

        model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='dis_conv_2'))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(name='dis_bc_2'))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2, name='dis_lr_2'))

        model.add(Flatten(name='dis_flatten'))

        model.add(Dense(256, name='dis_dense_1'))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2, name='dis_lr_4'))

        model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

        image = Input(self.img_shape, name='dis_input')
        valid = model(image)
        # model.summary()

        return Model(image, valid)

    def generate_real_samples(self):
        gen_imgs = np.random.normal(0, 1, (self.batch_size, self.latent_dim))
        labels = np.ones((self.batch_size, 1))
        return gen_imgs, labels

    def generate_fake_samples(self):
        noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, (self.batch_size, self.latent_dim))
        imgs = self.generator.predict(noise)
        labels = np.zeros((self.batch_size, 1))
        return imgs, labels

    def sample_original_image(self):
        idx = np.random.randint(0, self.samples, self.batch_size)
        imgs = self.X_train[idx]
        labels = np.ones((self.batch_size, 1))
        return imgs, labels

    def get_data(self):
        (X_train, _), (_, _) = cifar10.load_data()
        self.samples = X_train.shape[0]
        # Rescale the image to -1 to 1
        X_train = (X_train.astype('float32') - 127.5) / 127.5
        return X_train

    def train(self):
        self.X_train = self.get_data()

        mini_batch = int(self.batch_size / 2)
        for epoch in range(1, self.epochs+1):
            for batch in range(mini_batch):

                imgs, labels = self.sample_original_image()
                gen_imgs, gen_labels = self.generate_fake_samples()

                # Train the discriminator
                d_loss_real, _ = self.discriminator.train_on_batch(imgs, labels)
                d_loss_fake, _ = self.discriminator.train_on_batch(gen_imgs, gen_labels)

                # The generator wants the discriminator to label the generated samples
                # as valid (ones)
                noise, valid_y = self.generate_real_samples()

                # Train the generator
                g_loss = self.combined.train_on_batch(noise, valid_y)

            # Plot the progress every 100 iterations:
            if epoch % 10 == 0:
                print ("epoch: %d / %d [D loss real: %f, D loss fake: %f] [G loss: %f]" % (epoch, self.epochs, d_loss_real, d_loss_fake, g_loss))


img_rows, img_cols, channels, epochs, batch_size, latent_dim = 32, 32, 3, 100, 64, 100
cifar_gan = CifarGAN(img_rows, img_cols, channels, epochs, batch_size, latent_dim)
cifar_gan.train()
```

**Epochs**

```
epoch: 0 / 100 [D loss real: 0.000000, D loss fake: 15.942385] [G loss: 0.000000]
epoch: 10 / 100 [D loss real: 0.000000, D loss fake: 15.942385] [G loss: 0.000000]
epoch: 20 / 100 [D loss real: 0.000000, D loss fake: 15.942385] [G loss: 0.000000]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You set `self.discriminator.trainable = False`, isn't that the cause?

Comment: No. Although, `self.discriminator.trainable = False` is right but even if I make it `self.discriminator.trainable = True` there is no change. You can check it.

Comment: Something isnt right where you are building your discriminator. Uncomment `# self.combined.summary()` and you will see that the number of parameters in the discriminator is not equal to the number of non-trainable parameters in `combined`, which it should be. Try calling `model.build(input_shape)` on the `discriminator` and `generator` before you pass them to the `combined` model. This should also fix the issues you have with their summaries.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But still, it does not solve my problem. @FinleyGibson

Comment: Also please check out this GitHub issue regarding `model.build(input_shape)`. [click me](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5342#issuecomment-278736082)